# Finding Azure AD Schema Extension AppId in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

If one synchronizes custom attributes via Azure AD Connect, schema extensions are made to Azure AD and there is an associated application made in Azure AD with a `DisplayName` of "Tenant Schema Extension App".

Unfortunately, these extensions are uniquely named, as well with `extension_AppIdGuid_attributeName`.

With the Azure AD PowerShell module, it is easy enough to find this:

```ps
$ExtensionGuid = ((Get-AzureADApplication | 
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Tenant Schema Extension App"}).AppId).Replace("-","")
```

These can also be queried within the Microsoft Graph.  However, I cannot find a mechanism within the Microsoft Graph to find what the `AppId` is.

I have queried:

- `/organization`
- `/schemaExtensions`
- `/$metadata`

The Azure AD Graph seems to have the capability, but it is going away and the Microsoft Graph is the future.  I want it there.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the Tenant Schema Extension app in Microsoft Graph via the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=displayName eq 'Tenant Schema Extension App'
```

Unlike the Azure AD Graph which Application object which has an `id` and an `appId`, the Microsoft Graph Application object only has an `id` property which corresponds to the `appId` value in the Azure AD Graph.

**Note**: As per the Microsoft Graph documentation for [GET /applications](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_get) you require any the following permissions:

- **Delegated (work or school account)**:   Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All
- **Application**:  Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All

Comment: Awesome.  So, now I running into a permissions issue and I cannot seem to find out which permissions that I need to grant myself.  Any guidance on how to determine this?

Comment: Nevermind, I was just impatient.  It required: Directory.Read.All

Comment: Can you upvote the answer and flag the question as answered please?