# How to Find AppId of Schema Extention App in Azure AD

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have tried to get custom attributes created in Active directory using Microsoft graph. I am able to get attributes by their names using this query in Microsoft Graph

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=Department
```

But I'm not able to get some attributes which are not their by default (which are customly created) using microsoft graph. For an example, if I put "employeeId", the same query returns

```
{"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(employeeId)/$entity"}
```

Interestingly, I can get the employeeId using Azure AD graph which is now old school. (below query)

```html
https://graph.windows.net/me/employeeId
```

Above query returns me the following Jason

```
{
"odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/$metadata#Edm.String",
"value": "38XXX"}
```

After some googling, I've found that there are extension attributes which are created using Azure AD connect which will create a **Schema Extension App** in Azure and we can get them using

```
extension_{appID}_employeeId
```

I can't find any Schema Extension App in my Azure Portal and I've tried some Powershell commands too. Our organization don't use Azure B2C AD. What I need is

1. A way to find AppId of Schema Extension App in Azure
2. Or an alternative way to get those custom attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A way to find AppId of Schema Extension App in Azure

If you want to find the `AppId` of Schema Extension App, you could use the MS graph api below.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?$filter=displayName eq 'Tenant Schema Extension App'
```

[image]

For more details about required permission etc, refer to this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494863/finding-azure-ad-schema-extension-appid-in-microsoft-graph).

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But I've already tried that and no luck since it seems I don't have a Schema Extension App in Azure (Our tenant is not a B2C one)

Comment: @NiroshSns My tenant is also not a B2C one. If one synchronizes custom attributes via Azure AD Connect, schema extensions are made to Azure AD and there is an associated application made in Azure AD with a DisplayName of "Tenant Schema Extension App".

Comment: @NiroshSns You could also see this [link](http://www.idampundit.com/2017/05/extending-azure-ad-schema-via-graph-api-n00b-guide/), it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I've found the Tenant Schema Extension AppID buy running below query in Microsoft Graph Explorer

Note : Use Beta for Graph API version

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me
```

Which returned me a lengthy Json with below output

```
"userPrincipalName": "example@abc.com",
"externalUserState": null,
"externalUserStateChangeDateTime": null,
"userType": "Member",
"extension_{appid}_extensionAttribute3": "XXX",
"extension_{appid}_extensionAttribute2": "XXX",
"extension_{appid}_extensionAttribute1": "XXX",
"extension_{appid}_employeeID": "XXXXXX",
```

Additionally, the below query returned the extension attributes even without the appid (you should use beta version)

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?$select=UserPrincipalName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes
```

Which returned the below Json

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(userPrincipalName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes)/$entity",
"userPrincipalName": "xxxx@xxx.com",
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
    "extensionAttribute1": "XXX",
    "extensionAttribute2": "XXX",
    "extensionAttribute3": "XXX",
    "extensionAttribute4": null,
    "extensionAttribute5": null,
    "extensionAttribute6": null,
    "extensionAttribute7": null,
    "extensionAttribute8": null,
    "extensionAttribute9": null,
    "extensionAttribute10": null,
    "extensionAttribute11": null,
    "extensionAttribute12": null,
    "extensionAttribute13": null,
    "extensionAttribute14": null,
    "extensionAttribute15": null
}
```

}